# All users were deleted from the server

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, login

I restored the access using recovery,
but something weird happened:

all users, except `root` and `ram` were deleted from the server,
could've been that system was compromised, but nothing else is touched (at least I can't find any signs)

remote root login was disabled, password had 24 symbols, and SSH port wasn't default

I myself used ssh key to login, the other guy (only 2 has the access to the server) used the password, but he swears he store credentials safely and didn't share it with anyone

We have automated security updates enabled on the server, is there a chance it was done by one of it?

And if someone can suggest the further course of actions, I'd be glad to here, what can I do in this situation

**ORIGINAL Q:**

I have a server with Ubuntu 14.04, remote root login was disabled

there were several users created, but now (for some reasons) they all are unavailable. Someone changed the passwords/disabled ssh-keys login (there are only several people with access)

I have an option to reset the root's password, but I can't login directly via ssh. Also, there is webmin installed on the server.

Can someone suggest any options, how I can restore the control?

Comment: Sounds like you need to take it offline and fix via physical access, as it sounds like the system was compromised.

Comment: I've restored the access, but something appeared, I updated the question